# How to implement a listener for a row inside of a listView?

Tags: java, android, class, listview, listener

I have a listView of custom views. Each view contains an editText. I'm trying to add listeners to the editText variables which I create in the getView(). The problem is that when I create the listeners it doesn't let me use the editText variable unless I make it final, but if I make it final, I guess I'm going to have problems when the row gets reused. This is a simple example of what my problem is:

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Date>{

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            List<Date> objects) {

        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_cell_single, parent, false);
        }else{
            row = convertView;
        }

        EditText et = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText_single);
        et.setText("" + position);

        et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(!hasFocus){
                    et.setText("You edited row: " + position);
                    //Error: et must be final, position must be final
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare this `EditText et` as a class variable in `MyAdapter`. As

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Date>{
 EditText et;

}
```

And then initiate it in `getView();` method.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   //do your stuff
   ........
    et=(EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText_single);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a contract between scopes, i.e. the stack versus the heap. The reference created on the stack must be final to declare that the reference will not (and cannot) be changed since the reference is basically bound by the anonymous class (OnFocusChangeListener) using it.

The reference will not be reused since each stack will get its own copy of the reference to the EditText object.